# AND conditions in many-to-many relation

Tags: sql, postgresql, indexing, many-to-many, relational-division

Say I have three tables, a table of users, a table of around 500 different items, and the corresponding join table. What I would like to do is:

```
select * from users u join items_users iu on iu.user_id = u.id
where iu.item_id in (1,2,3,4,5)
and u.city_id = 1 limit 10;
```

Except, instead of an `IN` condition, I would like to find users that have *all* the corresponding items. If it helps, assume that the max number of items that will be searched for at a time will be 5. Also, I am using Postgres, and don't mind denormalizing it if would help as it's a read only system and speed is highest priority.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's another case of relational division. We have assembled quite an arsenal of queries to deal with this class of problems [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7364969/how-to-filter-sql-results-in-a-has-many-through-relation/7774879#7774879).

In this case, with 5 or more items, I might try:

```
SELECT u.*
FROM   users AS u
WHERE  u.city_id = 1
AND EXISTS (
   SELECT *
   FROM   items_users AS a
   JOIN   items_users AS b USING (user_id)
   JOIN   items_users AS c USING (user_id)
   ...
   WHERE  a.user_id = u.user_id
   AND    a.item_id = 1
   AND    b.item_id = 2
   AND    c.item_id = 3
   ...
   )
LIMIT 10;
```

It was among the fastest in my tests and it fits the requirement of multiple criteria on `items_users` while only returning columns from `user`.

Read about [indexes at the linked answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7364969/how-to-filter-sql-results-in-a-has-many-through-relation/7774879#7774879). these are crucial for performance.
As your tables are read-only I would also [`CLUSTER`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-cluster.html) both tables, to minimize the number of pages that have to be visited. If nothing else, CLUSTER `items_users` using a multi-column index on `(user_id, item_id)`.